Could we remove the sorting of attributes while using ST?
I have to generate a XML based on structures, I use Simple Transformation to generate it.
It seems that while performing the serialization there is an automatic sorting of the attributes of the XML.
Example, sample of ST :
<?sap.transform simple?> 
<tt:transform xmlns:tt="http://www.sap.com/transformation-templates" xmlns:ddic="http://www.sap.com/abapxml/types/dictionary" xmlns:def="http://www.sap.com/abapxml/types/defined" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">   <tt:root name="TOP" type="ddic:ZZ_STRUCTURE_XML"/>   
<tt:template>   
<Element1 tt:ref="TOP">       
<tt:attribute name="Name" value-ref="FIELD01"/>       
<tt:attribute name="Version" value-ref="FIELD02"/>       
<tt:attribute name="Tag" value-ref="FIELD03"/>     
</Element2>   
</tt:template> 
</tt:transform>

Expected result (XML) :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Element1 Name="xx" Version="xx" Tag="xx"/>

Actual result (XML) :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Element1 Name="xx" Tag="xx" Version="xx"/>

Is there a way to remove the alphabetical sorting of the attributes using ST ? I know that this unexpected sort doesn't have impact for the parsing of the XML but still it is not the expected result.

Why would anyone expect the XML attributes to be ordered? Except if this person is willing to use a non-compliant XML software to parse the XML file, just tell this person that this expectation is non-sense.

Unfortunately, you cannot control the order of attributes, as this depends on the implementation details of the underlying library. Therefore, there is no guarantee of a consistent order, which may vary based on the release version and / or the XML technology used.
As you correctly pointed out, the order of attributes is irrelevant according to the XML specification, and an XML parser should not expect a particular order. For reference, the XML specification states:

3.1 Start-Tags, End-Tags, and Empty-Element Tags
...
the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant


Generally, you shouldn't care about order of attributes, and most serialization libraries don't give you any control (though some retain the input order, to the extent that they know it).
Although it's theoretically irrelevant, XML is designed to be human-readable, so achieving a consistent attribute order is actually a reasonable aim - though software that processes XML should never rely on it. It can also be useful to deliver a canonical ordering so that two XML files can be compared lexically, which is why Canonical XML always puts attributes in alphabetical order.
The Saxon serializer [disclaimer: my company's product] in its commercial versions has an option to define a user-specified order of attributes: see https://www.saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters
